# Getting system color from CSS using jQuery in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, background-color, systemcolors

I have a css rule defining the background color as [the window system color](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#system-colors):

```
background-color: window;
```

When I try to get the background color using jQuery's css method: `$(selector).css("background-color");`. It works well in Google Chrome, it returns the correct color, albeit not as a system color, but translated to rgb(255,255,255). In IE9 it returns rgb(-1,-1,-1)... Which of course renders black and not white when applied.

Comment: For ScrollBar color it works in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/QK4gp/

Comment: why not use `#fff` or the `rbg()` if browser is `$.browser.msie`

Comment: $.browser *is* deprecated now and has been for some time, but it would be permissible to use in such circumstances...

Comment: A system color may not have a direct translation as an rgb. It's depedent on the system and as such I can't be the one to translate it. I can go around the problem by reading the style attribute myself, or setting an attribute with the background color, there I would have the exact word I want to put on my css. Styll, I'd like to know why this happens and checking if browser is IE is not a solution, because I still can't know what the system color for window is.

Comment: @kubedan no it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/QK4gp/6/ . I can set the color as a system color, what I can't is reading the color using css method. As you see, it draws correctly, but when I try to get the color it's rgb(-1,-1,-1) which probably means it's a system color, but it doesn't tell me which...

Comment: You can always just add an "ieX" class on to your <html> tag and style accordingly - if the situation becomes desperate. Also valid and acceptable by modern standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be the "answer" you're looking for - but a couple of notes:

As to "why this happens" - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358804(v=vs.85).aspx - particularly:

> Unlike the other named colors however, user-defined system colors have no numeric RGB equivalent because the exact color is not known until the Web page is viewed on the user's system.

also note:

> The system color names have been deprecated in the Cascading Style Sheets, Level 3 (CSS3) recommendation.

If it is an absolute requirement that you be able to determine the RGB color code of the user's system-color for window on IE then you could resort to https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/ to bridge the gap